# How to make uninst.exe by electron-forge 6 with squirrel-windows maker?

Tags: electron, electron-forge

Could electron-forge 6 make an uninstall.exe so that I don't need to come to control panel to uninstall the app?

How to make uninst.exe by electron-forge 6 with squirrel-windows maker?

```js
"config": {
    "forge": {
      "packagerConfig": {
        "icon": "./static/img/app.ico",
        "asar": true
      },
      "makers": [
        {
          "name": "@electron-forge/maker-squirrel",
          "config": {
            "name": "voerkaintercomclient",
            "setupExe": "myApp.exe",
            "setupIcon": "./static/img/app.ico",
            "copyright": "myApp",
            "noMsi": "false"
          }
        },
        {
          "name": "@electron-forge/maker-zip",
          "platforms": [
            "darwin"
          ]
        },
        {
          "name": "@electron-forge/maker-deb",
          "config": {}
        },
        {
          "name": "@electron-forge/maker-rpm",
          "config": {}
        }
      ]
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunetly Squirrel does not have an option to make uninstall file. So by the official way, it is not possible.

But you can make your own uninstall executable.
It's not that difficult, just make another app with squirrel.windows usage, you can remove all shortcuts of the original app, then you need to delete uninstall registry of your app from "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\your_app_name" and then delete all files from %LocalAppData%/your_app_name.